# Drawable assets keep changing when state of Activity is changed

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have two fragments in a single Activity, and fragments load one after other after some interval.

Both fragments use same image assets work fine in all situation excepts given.

When I launch my activity, first fragment is loaded, it has assets scaled properly, just before time of loading of second fragment, if I go to background and start some other application(in my case it is a game which is in full screen mode), and when I come back to my original application, second fragment is loaded but the assets are not loaded properly, they are scaled up.

How do I handle this situation?

I have multiple drawable folders for different screen sizes with similar images but different dimensions.

I tried using this

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize"
```

but it didn't work.